# ubuntu and Steam

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, steam, ubuntu-mate, apple

I had to go a long way round to get Steam, as I was getting Error 403 Forbidden.  I worked around that, but when Steam starts up, I get told it wants to add additional files.  When I click on the application, I get a message suggesting that I install these files.  When run I get the following dialogue in the console:

```
>Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
>   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
>[sudo] password for robert: 
>.............................................................................>.............................................................................>.............................................................................>.............W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial >Xerus_ - Release powerpc (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release >file.
>E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release >powerpc (20160719)/dists/xenial/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  Please use >apt-cdrom to allow APT to recognise this CD-ROM. 'apt-get update' cannot be >used to add new CD-ROMs
>E: Failed to fetch http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial>/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
>E: Failed to fetch http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial->updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: >2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
```

XXXXXXX

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libdb1-compat initscripts tzdata

Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
Press return to cont
```

Please can anyone advise?  I'm running a G5 PowerMac, running ubintu-MATE 16.04.   Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Where the XXXXXXX is were the following lines: 

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]

Could not include as am a new user.

Comment: Please use code formatting for error output (see http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)